# Web Scraping with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to get the release date from a youtube video using `BeautifulSoup4` but I'm not getting any results.

I looked in the source code and found out that the information that I need in inside a span tag:

```
<span class="date style-scope ytd-video-secondary-info-renderer">Publicado em 27 de out de 2016</span>
```

What I need is `Publicado em 27 de out de 2016`

But when I try to find this span tag I don't get anything

My code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


class Client(QWebPage):

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.on_page_load)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def on_page_load(self):
        self.app.quit()


url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSH77vnOGqU'
client_response = Client(url)
source = client_response.mainFrame().toHtml()

soup = bs(source, 'lxml')
js_test = soup.find_all('span', {'class':'date'})

print(len(js_test))
for i in js_test:
    print(i.text)
```

Output

```
0
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `selenium` if you are going to need a library for dynamic javascript scraping, if you're interested in a solution using selenium+phantomJS I'd be glad to write one.